# Alasql, export single xls sheet with multiple tables,

Tags: html, angularjs, excel, alasql

I'm using alasql to export to xls file. I'm able to export a HTML table to xls. But I have multiple tables in my HTML and I want export to xls which should have only one sheet with multiple tables; like image below.

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> hi i made small changes in alasql file
>
> //alasql
>
> ```
> Object.objsize = function(Myobj) {
>     var osize = 0, key;
>     for (key in Myobj) {
>         if (Myobj.hasOwnProperty(key)) osize++;
>     }
>     return osize;
> };
> ```
>
> var bigtable = undefined;
>               var tableindex = 0;
>               var reqSize = undefined;
>
> ```
>         data.forEach(function(entry, index) {
>             var objsize = Object.objsize(entry);
>
>             if(reqSize == undefined){
>                 reqSize = objsize;
>                 bigtable = tableindex;
>             }
>
>             if(reqSize < objsize){
>                 bigtable = tableindex;
>                 reqSize = objsize;
>             }
>             ++tableindex;
>         })
>
>         columns = Object.keys(data[bigtable]).map(function(columnid) {
>             return {columnid: columnid};
>         });
> ```
>
> // your HTML
>
> Name 
>        Number 
>       
>       
>       
>       
>          Prashanth 
>          756943912X 
>       
>       
>   
>    
>   
>         
>        Email 
>        Company 
>        Experience             
>          prasanthreddy568@gmail.com 
>          Aryagami 
>          4 years
>
> // your script  var fileName = "Users";  data1 = alasql('SELECT * FROM
>   HTML("#table1",{header:true})');  data2 = alasql('SELECT * FROM
>   HTML("#table2",{header:true})');  data = data1.concat(data2); 
>   alasql('SELECT * INTO CSV("' + fileName + '",{headers:false}) FROM ?',
>   [data]);